# Retornar uma lista de outra lista em Python

Tags: python

Dada uma lista de números inteiros e um número inteiro n, retorna outra lista, que contenha todos os números da lista original maiores que n. Não estou conseguindo fazer retornar a lista que preciso.

```
from typing import List
def maiores(numeros: List[int], n: int):
    for i in numeros:
        if i > n:
            return list(i)
```

Comment: Essa estrutura que você está querendo fazer se parece muito com uma árvore binária de busca, como as respostas já são excelentes vou deixar minha contribuição indicando um vídeo sobre a árvore binária de busca, se quiser dar uma olhada é bastante enriquecedor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmKkAQtnjsM&ab_channel=Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3oDin%C3%A2mica

Answer (score 0):

vc pode fazer o seguinte:

```
lista = [0, 1, 2, 3]
n = 1
lista_final = []

for elemento in lista:
    if elemento > n:
        lista_final.append(elemento)

print(lista_final) # [2, 3]
```

Comment: Eu tentei refazer utilizando oq vc mostrou mas so retorna None.                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                       
    from typing import List
    def maiores(numeros: List[int], n: int):
        lista_maiores = []
        for i in numeros:
            if i > n:
                lista_maiores.append(i)


    print(maiores([0, 1, 2, 3], 1))

Comment: olá testei a execução e esta tudo certo com o código q fiz. tente criar um arquivo novo com o final .py, copie e cole este código. Agora, basta ir no terminal e executar: python3 nome_arquivo.py

Comment: você tambem pode testar online, copie e cole o código da minha resposta neste interpretador online: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão poderemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def maiores(lis, n):
    maiores_numeros = list()
    for c in lis:
        if c >= n:
            maiores_numeros.append(c)
    return maiores_numeros


valores = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores da lista: ').split()))
num = int(input('Desejas retornar os números a partir de qual valor? '))

print(maiores(valores, num))
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores da lista:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. A partir deste momento a lista **valores** será montada com todos os valores digitados.

Posteriormente, receberemos a próxima mensagem: `Desejas retornar os números a partir de qual valor?` . Neste momento devemos digitar um **valor inteiro** que representará o limite inferior dos valores que queremos exibir.

A partir desse momento a lista **valores** e o número **num** serão passados como parâmetros para a função **maiores(lis, n)**. Chegando lá o bloco **for** irá iterar sobre a lista **lis** e, com a ajuda do bloco **if** verificará se o valor temporário da respectiva iteração - **c** - é maior oi igual ao valor **n**. Caso positivo, o respectivo valor será adicionado à lista **maiores_numeros** e, posteriormente, tal lista será exibida como retorno da função.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:**

Caso, o valor digitado para a variável **num** seja um número que esteja fora do intervalo fechado dos valores pertencentes à lista **valores**, o retorno da função será uma **lista vazia**.

**Testando  código:**

**Exemplo 1**

Ao executarmos o código e digitarmos os seguintes valores:

```
2 9 3 8 4 7
```

E digitarmos o valor:

```
5
```

Receberemos como saída:

```
[9, 8, 7]
```

**Exemplo 2**

Ao executarmos o código e digitarmos os seguintes valores:

```
2 9 3 8 4 7
```

E digitarmos o valor:

```
9
```

Receberemos como saída:

```
[9]
```

**Exemplo 3**

Ao executarmos o código e digitarmos os seguintes valores:

```
2 9 3 8 4 7
```

E digitarmos o valor:

```
10
```

Receberemos como saída:

```
[]
```

Neste último exemplo receberemos uma lista vazia como retorno da função. Isto ocorre, porque não existe na lista **valores** números maiores ou iguais a **10**.

Comment: @Marco Raad, faça testes com este código.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma função que ja retorna a lista.

Aqui definimos a lista e qual será o valor de n (este digitado pelo usuário):

```
lista_numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
n = int(input('Valor para n: '))
```

Definimos a função maiores, que utiliza list comprehension(gera uma lista de saída):

```
def maiores(lista,n):
    return [i for i in lista if i > n]
```

Aqui chamamos a função, guardamos o resultado um uma variavel, depois utilizamos o print para mostrar o resultado:

```
lista_retorno = maiores(lista_numeros,n)
print(lista_retorno)
```

Saída:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8] # o n de exemplo foi 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa mais simples seria filtrar a sua lista através da função *built-in* [`filter(funcao, iteravel)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter) auxiliado por uma *[expressão lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)*.

```
lista = [7, 9, 67, 44, 35, 14, 95, 7, 6, 78, 33]

def maiores( l , n ):
  #Para cada elemento da lista l filtra apenas os elementos maiores e iguais a n.
  return list( filter( lambda e: e >= n , l ) )

print( maiores( lista , 34 ) )
```

<sup>Teste o código no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ToughLankyMention)</sup>
Resultado:

```
[67, 44, 35, 95, 78]
```

Se precisar ordenar o resultado use a função *built-in* [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
print( sorted( maiores( lista , 8 ) ) )
```